# Change skinning.ecss for my application

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I need fully change UI style existing application. 
How to tell to RichFaces that, I want use another EL CSS file for skinning? 
Where to put new .ecss file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to fully change the RichFaces skin you cand add this to your web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.skin</param-name>
    <param-value>skin_name</param-value>
</context-param>
```

and some of the skin's are: emeraldTown, blueSky, wine, japanCherry, ruby, classic, deepMarine etc.

But if you want to change something to your current(or default skin), you can do that with .ecss file.

More on this you can find here: http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_2_X/Developer_Guide/en-US/html/chap-Developer_Guide-Skinning_and_theming.html

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thank for answer, but I want change exactly ecss file. I know that Richfaces use a ECSS template file (skinning.ecss) and inserts a values from skin file to this file. How change standart skinning.ecss to another?

Comment: So you want to change the skinning.eccs with another file (e.g. myFile.eccs)? But why should you do that, if you can just overwrite the css from skinning.eccs? For example if you want to apply some css to <rich:panel>, you use .rf-p {} in your css file and it will overwrite the rich faces panel css! In the link I gave you, you have details with every change you can make regarding this... I hope I've understand it correctly want you want! :)

Answer (score 0):

Richfaces explicitely [describes](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_2_X/Developer_Guide/en-US/html/chap-Developer_Guide-Skinning_and_theming.html#sect-Developer_Guide-Skinning_and_theming-ECSS_files) the modification of .ecss files.

You could do so by creating a jar for your custom skin and add the .ecss files into this archive.

The custom skin jar has the structure:

```
└───META-INF
    │   faces-config.xml
    │   MANIFEST.MF
    │
    ├───resources
    │   │   skinning.ecss
    │   │   skinning_both.ecss
    │   │   skinning_classes.ecss
    │   │
    │   └───org.richfaces
    │           collapsiblePanel.ecss
    │           datascroller.ecss
    │           panel.ecss
    │           panelMenu.ecss
    │           popupPanel.ecss
    │           tabPanel.ecss
    │           toolbar.ecss
    │
    └───skins
            common.skin.properties
```

**But be aware.** I experienced the problem that Richfaces (4.3.7) *not always* prefers your custom ecss files over its standard ones!
The only solution I figured out was deleting the relevant .ecss files from the richfaces-components-ui.jar